# Specific JavaScript function to swap CSS style sheets with drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I understand that this type of question has been answered before, however I have to use some provided JavaScript to pass an assignment for my class, (It's very important that I use the provided JavaScript) and I'm having difficulty following the provided instructions to make my style sheets swap on command.

The instructions are as follows:

> *The function setStyleSource( ) takes two arguments, a string that is the value of the id attribute of the link element you want to change, and a string that is the filename, or path plus filename, or URL of the CSS file you want to load. To make a click on an element load this stylesheet and discard the previous stylesheet, make a call to it the value of the element’s onclick event attribute.*
>
> ```
> <p class="stylechange" onclick="setStyleSource(‘changeable’, ‘alt2.css’)"> … </p>
> ```

Here is the provided JavaScript code:

> ```
> function setStyleSource (linkID, sourceLoc) {
>            var theLink = document.getElementById(linkID);
>            theLink.href = sourceLoc;
>        }
> ```

And here are segments of my code both the CSS pages with different ID attributes and my attempt at creating a p element the same as the instructions, only with my ID and CSS link attributes:

```
<head>      
        <title>CRAFT412 - Info</title>      
        <link href="css/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="s1" id="s1"/>  
        <link href="css/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="s2" id="s2"/>
        <link href="css/styles3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="s3" id="s3"/>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="CTEC1800-Stylesheets.js"> </script>     
    </head>
```

`<p onclick="setStyleSource('2', 'styles2.css')">style 2</p>`

I'd like this to work on a drop down menu so you can select which style sheet you want to change too on the drop down, but I'm not sure how to implement this with the JavaScript provided, I'm clearly doing something wrong and just need some help with these instructions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: id and title can not be a part of link element.

Comment: @fruitjs well i'm just trying to follow the instructions i don't really know what i'm doing at all. I need an example really.

Comment: @fruitjs Yes they can - please research before making such statements https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-link-element.html

Comment: @fruitjs A `<link>` element CAN include an `id=""` AND `title=""` since it can include the "global" attributes and those are some of those. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link Globals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes - adding this to add the two references

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - I've commented it up too

[Here's a fiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/jf7Lusgn/1/)

```
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="s1" id="s1"/>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="style1.css">Style1.css</option>
  <option value="style2.css">Style2.css</option>
  <option value="style3.css">Style3.css</option>
</select>

/* the function which changes the src */
function setStyleSource (linkID, sourceLoc) {
  var theLink = document.getElementById(linkID);
  theLink.href = sourceLoc;
  console.log(theLink.href); //* console log to make sure */
}

/* this is a listener to listen for changes on the dropdown */
document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; /* the option chosen */
    setStyleSource ("s1", selected)
});
```

You could also use the `onchange` property of the select:

This is without the listener being needed, all you need is:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="setStyleSource ('s1', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="style1.css">Style1.css</option>
  <option value="style2.css">Style2.css</option>
  <option value="style3.css">Style3.css</option>
</select>

/* the function which changes the src */
function setStyleSource (linkID, sourceLoc) {
  var theLink = document.getElementById(linkID);
  theLink.href = sourceLoc;
}
```

Comment: Could you do the drop down menu with html and css? I wasn't really clear but i'm just confused how to use the provided JavaScript with a normal html drop down list from a form or something. This assignment isn't really about JavaScript which is why he gave us some to use as we don't have to understand it.

Comment: Updated answer, is that what you mean?

Comment: I think that's more like it but, I can't use any other JavaScript, just the tiny part that I've been provided with.

Comment: I think my teacher said something about using an on click event on the drop down menu, but i'm not sure how i'd link the function to the drop down menu.

Comment: You don't use an `onclick` event on a dropdown - it's `onchange` - and you can delete the added javascript line `console.log(theLink.href);` it does not affect the function

Comment: ok fair enough, it's the listener part you did, is this needed? I want exactly what you did without the additional Listener JavaScript, it's hard to explain.

Comment: Updated answer again @GR412

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, the drop down menu is there but it doesn't change the style sheet, i'm not sure what values need changing.

Comment: Yeah I'm probably implementing implementing it wrong but when I select the second style sheet on the drop down menu, nothing happens. It should change the style sheet,